# How can I use Sonar with our project, which is built with ant?

Tags: java, sonarqube

We build our projects with ant and happy with it.

The other day, I wished to give Sonar a try only to discover that it requires me to have maven. So, I guess I need some kind of pom.xml somewhere in my project.

There are three things I wish to avoid:

- Learn maven **right now** (in general I may want to, but not now)
- Migrate to maven from ant
- Maintain two build scripts - one for ant and the other for maven.

Is it possible to have this pom.xml as minimal as possible and yet to be able to analyze the project with Sonar?

Thanks.

**P.S.**

Less demanding Sonar alternatives are welcome as well.

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task

Comment: Please, arrange your comment as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as requested, putting this as an answer:

[SONAR comes with an ANT task](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE44/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task)

Also look at [this](http://frommyworkshop.blogspot.com/2011/04/analyse-with-ant-sonar-way.html).

Answer (score 2):

Sonar version 2.6 introduced an [ANT task](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task) for running Sonar.

Code coverage reporting requires additional work. See the following answer:

[SONAR - Measure Code Coverage using Cobertura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747587/sonar-measure-code-coverage-using-cobertura/7760960#7760960)